# Getting a (null) result when attempting to format NSDate from MySQL datetime string

Tags: ios, objective-c, datetime, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have the following code:

```
- (NSString *)
  lastSeenDateString:(NSString *)dateString
{
  NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
  [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ"];
  NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

  NSString *result = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:date dateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle timeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];

  return result;
}
```

The `dateString` variable looks like this (I output to the log to make sure): 2014-05-20T17:23:42.000Z

The `date` variable, when output to log, shows: (null)

I've tried removing the `setTimeZone` method, changing `setDateFormat` to things many different things ("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", "yyyy-MM-dd", etc.) and nothing works. No matter what I do, it returns null. I've looked at many other StackOverflow questions answering the same thing, as well as other samples on Google, and my code seems to line up with accepted answers. Yet, still nothing but a null NSDate variable results.

Comment: Should be "...:mm:ss.SSSZ"

Comment: You really should learn how to work this out for yourself.  Starting from the doc for NSDateFormatter you can follow several links to get to the standard for date format strings.  Study that document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input doesn't match the format.

```
 [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'SSSZ" ];
```

Comment: Single quotes are only necessary to disambiguate.

Comment: And the above will only work for a literal Z timezone.

Comment: Just to clarify, Naveen fixed this so it no longer requires the literal `Z` time zone.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the `T` in single quotes, and you should include the milliseconds, `SSS`, in the format string.

Your date string appears to be a RFC 3339 date. As outlined in [Technical Q&A 1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1480/_index.html), to make sure you handle different international calendar settings, you want to parse that in the `en_US_POSIX` locale.

Thus:

```
- (NSString *)lastSeenDateString:(NSString *)dateString
{
    NSLocale *enUSPOSIXLocale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];

    // parse RFC 3339 date

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    dateFormatter.locale = enUSPOSIXLocale;
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ";
    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

    // switch back to current locale

    dateFormatter.locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];

    return [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:date dateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle timeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
}
```